# Need Javascript syntax to reference a CSS class instead of HTML element

Tags: javascript

I searched online for the correct syntax to reference a CSS class, instead of an HTML element, but was unable to find anything helpful.

I would like to modify the code below to reference any DIV of class buy_content "div.buy_content" instead of the body element.

```
<a href="#" onclick="body.style.fontSize='1em'; set_cookie('page_size', '1', 30);">Small Text</a>
<a href="#" onclick="body.style.fontSize='2em'; set_cookie('page_size', '2', 30);">Medium Text</a>
<a href="#" onclick="body.style.fontSize='3em'; set_cookie('page_size', '3', 30);">Large Text</a>
```

Comment: You don't need "javascript:" for "onclick" attribute values.

Answer (score 3):

There is no "JavaScript syntax" for what you're asking for.  Newer browsers support an API called "getElementsByClassName", so you could do this:

```
function setSize(sz) {
  var elements = document.getElementsByClassName('buy_content');
  for (var i = 0; i < elements.length; ++i) {
    if (elements[i].tagName === 'DIV')
      elements[i].style.fontSize = sz;
  }
}

<a href='#' onclick='setSize("1em"); set_cookie(...);'>Small</a>
```

You can find a "patch" for "getElementsByClassName" support [here](http://robertnyman.com/2008/05/27/the-ultimate-getelementsbyclassname-anno-2008/).

Comment: Recommend `querySelectorAll` over `getElementsByClassName` since IE8 supports the former.

Comment: There *are* ways in javascript to do EXACTLY what he asked for (referencing CSS and it's classes). I described precisely what he asked in my answer.

Comment: Well sure, but that's not "JavaScript syntax".  In other words, JavaScript runtime facilities in a web browser definitely support many ways of solving the problem, but it's not really part of the syntax of the language like (for example) an "if" statement is part of the syntax.

Comment: @Raynos It would be interesting to see a jsperf test between those :-)

Answer (score 0):

You can't really do this (easily/readably/cleanly) with inline and stock JavaScript because the JavaScript DOM API doesn't provide a way to reference a CSS class since this isn't part of the DOM.  You would have to populate an array or list with HTML elements that have that class applied to them and then iterate over the collection.

JQuery provides selectors and iterators to make this very simple, but if you can't use libraries then doing this inline isn't a good idea.  Put it in a function in a script block or an external .js file.

EDIT:

A few people pointed out `querySelectorAll`, which will select by class but from what I have read isn't completely cross platform (doesn't work on IE below IE 8).

Further, to clarify on my original post, when I said that the DOM API doesn't allow you to access an element by class, what I meant was that it couldn't be done with **DOM traversal**.  `querySelectAll` or the JQuery selectors perform DOM traversal with functions that inspect elements and their properties, retrieve the objects, and populate collections.  Even `getElementById` performs attribute inspection.  I suppose, in retrospect, it's a moot point, but since he wasn't using selectors or attribute queries in his original code I thought that he was asking if there was JS syntax that was as simple as what he was currently using.  That's why I mentioned functions.  In my head, even something like `getElementById` is a function since, well, it is a function.

Comment: Since when were classes not part of the DOM?

Comment: A class is an ATTRIBUTE of an element in the DOM.  It is not part of the DOM itself.

Comment: Ever heard of `querySelectorAll` ? That's part of the DOM.

Comment: The Document Object Model is populated by elements.  Elements have attributes that can be used to select objects in the DOM.  A class is not part of the Document Object Model, it is an attribute of elements in the DOM tree that can be used as a selector.  I'm referring to the DOM as a Model, not a Spec.  I figured that specifying that would be redundant since the M stands for Model.

Comment: @DougStephen "the JavaScript DOM API" contains `querySelectorAll`

Comment: Right, and the API is not the Model, it's the Application Programming Interface TO the DOM.  EDIT:  Additionally, the new W3C Selector API doesn't work on IE below IE8 so I wouldn't count on it as a solution.

Comment: @DougStephen your contradicting what you wrote though. You say that "this can't be done because the DOM API doesn't provide a way to reference CSS classes" where as it can.

Comment: @Raynos fair point, I edited one of my comments to (sort of) reflect that.  The W3C Selector API isn't cross platform.

Comment: @DougStephen What do you mean? `querySelectorAll` is supported in all recent browsers and the previous version of all those browsers.

Comment: @Raynos http://ajaxian.com/archives/creating-a-queryselector-for-ie-that-runs-at-native-speed  An article discussing the need to hand-roll a solution for querySelectors on IE7 and Lower.  It's also in the MSDN KB's.

Comment: @DougStephen but we have IE8 / IE9 so unless you targeting an audience that uses legacy browsers this isn't a problem.

Comment: @Raynos agreed, and in a perfect world I'd say leave them behind too, but most very large sites that report browser statistics still show that IE 6 and 7 combined usually account for around 10% of their traffic.  Not a large number but that's still something that should be accounted for.  Why use a method that'll kill off 10% of people who visit your site when you can use something like JQuery that supports IE6+

Comment: @DougStephen I tend to interpret the DOM api as any method defined on `document`. As for IE6/7 the statistics are skewed. Large corporate businesses use old versions of IE. China uses IE6. Generic public facing websites don't have to worry too much about IE6/7, in fact they should recommend users to upgrade their browsers.

Comment: @Raynos I guess my exposure to old browsers is a little skewed myself having spent a good amount of time working for a defense contractor.  I do completely agree with you in regards to recommending upgrades.  And the DOM API does define any methods defined on document.  But the API isn't the DOM.  That's all I was saying.  And yes, I do realize that I was splitting hairs.  Probably not the best way to approach answering the question.

Comment: @DougStephen it's fine, you've cleared it up. It's a pity to be in government / corporate sectors where using IE6 is the norm :\

Comment: We were lucky in that we didn't have that enforcement in our office.  But our clients did since our customers were government.  The last 2-3 months that I worked there, I switched off of being a software dev and helped redesign the company website. So I got hammered with legacy compatibility since anything that failed to be compatible could have been a lost customer.

Comment: @Doug: *"A class is an ATTRIBUTE of an element in the DOM. It is not part of the DOM itself."* I don't think that's right. An attribute is part of the DOM as a DOM nodeType 2. [Example.](http://jsfiddle.net/8QxCQ/)

Comment: @patrick [From the W3C Schools site](http://www.w3schools.com/htmldom/dom_nodes_info.asp), you can see that the DOM is defined as being comprised of Nodes, and each Node has 3 important properties.  nodeType is a property of a Node.

Comment: @DougStephen I'm afraid you can't quote W3Schools. It's not a reputable website ;) [Follow the campaign](http://w3fools.com/). If you quote me a definition from W3C then I'll take it seriously. W3schools just writes any half baked nonsense it feels lik

Comment: @Doug: Yes sir, but that's my point. The DOM is comprised of Nodes, Nodes have a nodeType, an Attribute is a Node with a nodeType, therefore an Attribute is part of the DOM. Or have I misunderstood your point?

Comment: [Level 2 HTML DOM Spec](http://www.w3.org/TR/2003/REC-DOM-Level-2-HTML-20030109/).  Attributes are a property of the objects listed in the HTML DOM.  Unless I'm completely misunderstanding the spec.

Comment: @Doug: Yes, there are some attributes that become exposed as properties on the host objects, and there is mapping between the properties and attributes in certain cases, but I believe that is a separate matter from their representation as nodes in the DOM. Although I may be the one who is misunderstanding the spec.

Comment: @patrick I know that the XML DOM spec puts Attributes in the tree, but I don't think HTML does.  Not 100% on that one.

Answer (score 0):

My **first** suggestion to answer your exact question:

If your project is bigger in scope than just this one thing:

1. Download jQuery
2. Use code:

   ```
   $('div.buy_content')
   ```

   Which returns a jQuery array object of all the divs which you can further manipulate.

My **second** suggestion based on thinking more deeply about what you're trying to do:

Either completely replace the stylesheet in script or modify the existing stylesheet to change the style. Don't loop through all the DIVs in the document and change their style assignment, instead change the meaning of their already-assigned style.

Comment: jQuery isn't needed for just this.

Comment: No, but I bet you the OP's overall project needs something like it.

Answer (score 0):

```
<a href="#" class="clickie size-1" >Small text </a>
<a href="#" class="clickie size-2" >Medium text </a>
<a href="#" class="clickie size-3" >Large text </a>
```

You should change the markup not to rely on inline javascript.

```
// bind the event handler to all <a> tags
var as = document.getElementsByTagNames("a");
for (var i = 0, ii = as.length; i < ii; i++) {
    as[i].onclick = setText;
}

function setText(ev) {
    // get the em size from the class
    var size = /[.]*text-([\d][.]*)/.exec(ev.target.className)[1]
    var divs = document.querySelectorAll("div.buy_content");
    // set the style on all divs.
    for (var i = 0, ii = divs.length; i < ii; i++) {
        divs[i].style.fontSize = size + "em";
    }
}
```

There are issues with browser support (mainly IE7 and lower) so you need some more boilerplate to make it work.

Answer (score 0):

I believe what you are looking for is insertRule (this is **exactly** what you asked for... kinda):

`document.styleSheets[document.styleSheets.length-1].insertRule('div.buy_content {font-size: 1em}',document.styleSheets[document.styleSheets.length-1].length)`

`document.styleSheets[document.styleSheets.length-1]` is your last stylesheet.
the new rule will go at index `document.styleSheets[document.styleSheets.length].length`

http://www.quirksmode.org/dom/w3c_css.html#t22

also... deleteRule:

http://www.quirksmode.org/dom/w3c_css.html#t21

**BUT,** a better way to go would be to getElementsByClassName, loop through em, check their nodeName for "DIV", then apply the styles the old fashioned way.

Comment: btw. IE hasn't supported most styleSheet functions until IE9.

Comment: not strictly true. It has proprietary named versions of the W3C standard that work in much the same way.

Answer (score 0):

Leverage CSS to do the selection work for you:

```
body.smalltext  .buy_content { font-size: 1em; }
body.mediumtext .buy_content { font-size: 2em; }
body.largetext  .buy_content { font-size: 3em; }

...

<input type="button" value="Small text"  id="smalltext"/>
<input type="button" value="Medium text" id="mediumtext"/>
<input type="button" value="Large text"  id="largetext"/>

...

document.getElementById('smalltext').onclick= function() {
    document.body.className= 'smalltext';
};
document.getElementById('mediumtext').onclick= function() {
    document.body.className= 'mediumtext';
};
document.getElementById('largetext').onclick= function() {
    document.body.className= 'largetext';
};
```